# Create a named range based on a value in another column not included in range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set, 10 columns wide, with an ever increasing number of rows.

In column C I have a set of features, e.g. "Search" that will have a few rows corresponding to it; ""Filter" that will have a few rows corresponding to it and so on. However, these could be in any order, so I could have some "Search" features and then some "Filter" features and then some more "Search" features...

I need to create a named range for selected cells in columns D:F where the value in C is the feature I require. This would be for example a named range called "T1" that goes from `D3:F6` and maybe `D71:F71` for all the "Search" features, but not the "Filter" features.

I have tried using Offset and Count in the Name Manager. But ideally, I need to use VBA in my already existing macro so I don't need to go in and change the Named Ranges every time a new row is added.

Ideally the code would be along the lines of...
If column C contains the word "Filter", make a named range for the three columns to the right of it, every time the word "Filter" occurs.

I used Offset and Count in the name manager:

`=OFFSET(Features!$D$3, 0, 0, COUNTA(Features!$D$3:$D$9), COUNTA(Features!$D$3:$F$3))`

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim Features As Worksheet
    Dim myNamedRange As Range

    Dim myRangeName As String
    Set Features = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Search")

    If Range.("C") is "Search"
    Set mRangeName= myWorksheet.Range("D:F")

    myRangeName = "Search"

    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Search, RefersTo:=myNamedRange

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated. I hope I have clarified the problem enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you could try something like the following:

```
Sub test()
Dim featuresRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet")
Set featuresRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("C1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'dynamically set the range of features
counter = 0 'this counter will help us avoid Union(Nothing, some range), which would give an error

For Each cell In featuresRng 'loop through the range of features
    If cell.Value = "search" Then
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = 1 Then
            Set rng = sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))) 'build the range
        End If
    End If
Next cell
Debug.Print rng.Address
sht.Names.Add "Something", rng
End Sub
```

The code above, loops through the range of features and whenever a cell whose value is "search" is found, it adds the corresponding D, E and F cells in a range. In the end you have a total range which you can name whatever you want.

For example, if you have the following set-up:

[image]

Then what you'll get is this:

[image]

So the resulting range address would be `$D$1:$F$2,$D$8:$F$8,$D$10:$F$12,$D$15:$F$19`

Now, if you want individual named ranges to be created every time the keyword is found you can modify the code accordingly like so:

```
Sub test2()
Dim featuresRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet")
Set featuresRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("C1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'dynamically set the range of features
counter = 0
For Each cell In featuresRng
    If cell.Value = "search" Then
        counter = counter + 1
        Set rng = sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3))
        sht.Names.Add "Something" & counter, rng
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: this is absolutely perfect thank you so so much! Thanks for the explanations as well, I am sure I will end up using dynamic range again in VBA.

Comment: @PKen  Glad I could help! :)

Comment: another quick question? If I want to form a range based on two criteria, can I use the same method?

Comment: @PKen Sure. Just combine your criteria with any combination of `AND`, `OR` or any other logical operator and adjust the `if - then` statement accordingly. Of course you might need to further modify the above code depending on what exactly you want to do. Try your best and if you can't do it then post a new question ;)

Comment: Hi @Stavros Jon :) I have posted a new question - sorry to bother you but you were so helpful before! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559947/create-a-range-based-on-criteria-in-two-columns