# How to extend named range with VBA using offset

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that I am using in VBA for excel.

It goes through the my table, and creates a named range based on the values in column B ("OSI") and column C (i,e "Reporting")

```
Sub Round2()

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Features")

'Reporting and OSI

Set featuresRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("B1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
rngArray = featuresRng
ReDim NewArr(1 To 1)
y = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(rngArray)
    If rngArray(i, 2) = "Reporting" And rngArray(i, 1) = "OSI" Then
        ReDim Preserve NewArr(1 To y)
        NewArr(y) = featuresRng.Rows(i).Offset(0, 2).Address
        y = y + 1

    End If
Next i

sRng = Join(NewArr, Application.DecimalSeparator)
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "OSIRep", sht.Range(sRng)

End Sub ()
```

It is creating a named range that is two columns wide (column D to column E) when I want the range instead to go from column D to column F.

I am not sure which parts of the code to edit - I appreciate this is probably a very easy solution but I am having trouble!

Comment: As @Pᴇʜ suggested, change `featuresRng.Rows(i).Offset(0, 2).address` for `featuresRng.Rows(i).Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 3).address`, it should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this

```
NewArr(y) = featuresRng.Rows(i).Resize(1, 5).Offset(0, 3).Address
```

Comment: It would be more clear to just add the resize afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Range.Resize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) to resize a range. `Offset` only moves a range.

For example if your range is defined as

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("D:E")
```

and you want to extend it by 1 column to column F you can do it with

```
Set rng = rng.Resize(ColumnSize:=rng.Columns.Count + 1) 'extend range by 1 column
Debug.Print rng.Address 'will return $D:$F
```

Comment: @PEH thank you for the explanation, I will use Resize in the future :)