# Creating Named Range From data with criteria

Tags: excel, vba, criteria

I came across this code that was provided on a prior question on this topic.  It is the exact issue I am trying to solve.

I pasted the code, changed the column range to "A", as my values are in Columns A & B.  Column A is my "Category" or criteria and I want Column B to be the values displayed in the named range.

Here is my column data:

[image: pic of data]

When I run the code, I am getting an error:

> 1004: Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet'Failed

[image: pic of error]

It Debugs at:
`Set rng = sht.Range(cell.Offset(0,1))`

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim featuresRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long
Dim cell As Range
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Category Details")
Set featuresRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("A1"), sht.Range("A" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'dynamically set the range of features
counter = 0 'this counter will help us avoid Union(Nothing, some range), which would give an error
For Each cell In featuresRng 'loop through the range of features
    If cell.Value = "Essential Oils" Then
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = 1 Then
            Set rng = sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1))
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1))) 'build the range
        End If
   End If
Next cell
Debug.Print rng.Address
sht.Names.Add "Something", rng
End Sub`
```

Comment: Clearly I don't understand the code options.

Comment: `Set rng = cell.Offset(0,1)`?

Comment: is there a way to edit my question, so I can try and show the code correctly?

Comment: @BigBen I changed that line and it continued to work, but then debugged at: Set rng = Union(rng, sht.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1)))

Comment: `...Union(rng, cell.Offset(0,1))` probably.

Comment: It is exactly the same problem... `Set rng = Union(rng, cell.Offset(0, 1))`

Comment: Thank you @Scott Craner ! :)

Comment: Can you add a link to the other question to which you are referring.

Comment: THANK YOU @BIGBEN !  and FaneDuru !  Those changes worked!

Comment: Here is the prior question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539285/create-a-named-range-based-on-a-value-in-another-column-not-included-in-range

Comment: @Scott Craner Ok, well it worked, but I'm trying to use the named range in a Data Validation List.  It won't use this named range.  Any suggestions?